# Elastic Search Python: must inlcuded all words and sorted by word order to results

Tags: python, elasticsearch

must included all words and sorted by word order to results of Elastic Search

How to do that?

i mean i have python query:

```
result = es.search(index="main_database", body={"query": {"match": {'Full_texts':es_query}}}, size=50)
```

problem is: at least one word is in 'Full_texts' then it gives to me results.

**For me i want all words must included and keep word orders.**

> for example: the top of search result is fulfilled with all above
> like my requirements AND mid and bottom results is same as default Elastic search results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [intervals query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-intervals-query.html) or [span near](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-near-query.html)

With respectively with `ordered` or `in_order` parameter

Comment: so how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [operator `and`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) for your Elasticsearch match query.

The search query will be

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "Full_texts": {
                "query": "<your_query_input_goes_here>",
                "operator": "and"
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

However, **the word order is not guaranteed**, if you strictly need the words to follow order, please also refer to [the answer of @ExploZe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69172899/5668956)